# MySQL Deadlock - accessing different primary key values also creating deadlock

Tags: mysql, multithreading, sql-update, sql-delete

I went through MySQL logs and found the reason for deadlock

**1st thread** is trying to execute below query. Which is waiting for thread 2.

```
UPDATE M_SAMP SET FLAG=0 WHERE M_ID IN (SELECT M_ID FROM MM_RVW_SAMP WHERE TARGET_M_ID IN(19))
```

The result of inner query (`SELECT M_ID FROM MM_RVW_SAMP WHERE TARGET_M_ID IN(19)`) is `M_ID = 3562`.

**2nd thread** is executing below query.

```
DELETE FROM M_SAMP WHERE M_ID=3455
```

There is `no foreign key` relation defined in M_SAMP and MM_RVW_SAMP tables. And M_ID is primary key of M_SAMP table. And engine is `InnoDB`. And this issue is repeating.

Can any one help me, how locks are granted because of which deadlock is happening?

Logs

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2015-02-23 10:52:28 de8
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 13275344, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 25 lock struct(s), heap size 2408, 1394 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 1455, OS thread handle 0x11ac, query id 39660 xyz 192.168.1.108 userName Sending data
UPDATE M_SAMP SET FLAG=0 WHERE M_ID IN (SELECT M_ID FROM MM_RVW_SAMP WHERE TARGET_M_ID IN(19))
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 61569 page no 65 n bits 176 index `PRIMARY` of table `dbName`.`m_samp` trx id 13275344 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 29; compact format; info bits 0

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 13275335, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
254 lock struct(s), heap size 27512, 21595 row lock(s), undo log entries 7
MySQL thread id 1458, OS thread handle 0xde8, query id 39664 xyz 192.168.1.108 userName updating
DELETE FROM M_SAMP WHERE M_ID=3455
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 61569 page no 65 n bits 176 index `PRIMARY` of table `dbName`.`m_samp` trx id 13275335 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 29; compact format; info bits 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: Problem got resolved by executing inner query of update query and passing the returned value to update query. But still I want to know what type of locking is happening when I am directly executing update query with inner query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is given [here (on dba.stackexchange)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93642/58318) by @jynus.

Now I am using below update query.

```
UPDATE M_SAMP M 
JOIN MM_RVW_SAMP MM 
ON M.M_ID = MM. M_ID 
SET M.FLAG = 1 
WHERE MM.TARGET_M_ID = 19;
```